# Simple question about a limit

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following data:

1) $u(t), u'(t)$ and $u''(t)$ are bounded

2) $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow+\infty}{u(t)}=l$

3) $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow+\infty}{u'(t)}=0$

4) $u''(t)+cu'(t)+f(u)=0$ where $f$ is continuous and $c>0$

Why does $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow+\infty}{u''(t)}=0$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: From the differential equation in 4) I get that $\lim_{t \rightarrow +\infty} u''(t) = -f(l)$. I don't see why that is necessarily zero.

Comment: Yes, but intuitively the limit is $0$. The question may be solved using the fact that $u'' = (u')'$ and the fact $u'\rightarrow0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions 2) and 3) tell us that $u''(t)$ converges to $-f(\ell)$ as $t \to +\infty$. Suppose for instance, that $f(\ell) < 0$. Then there exists $t_0$ such that $t \geq t_0 \implies u''(t) \geq -\frac{1}{2}f(\ell) > 0$. This yields
$$
u'(t)-u'(t_0) = \int_{t_0}^tu''(s)\,ds\geq-\frac{1}{2}f(\ell)(t-t_0)\xrightarrow[t\to+\infty]{} +\infty
$$
which is absurd since $\lim_{t\to\infty} u'(t)=0$.

In the same way, $f(\ell) > 0$ is absurd and we must have
$$
\lim_{t\to +\infty} u''(t) = -f(\ell) = 0.
$$

---

**Edit:** (this is an answer to your comment) The hypothese $\lim_{t\to 0} u'(t)=0$ is not sufficient to prove $\lim_{t\to \infty} u''(t)=0$.
For example,
$$
u'(t) = \int_t^\infty \sin(e^u)\,du \xrightarrow[t\to\infty]{}0
$$
whereas $u''(t) = -\sin(e^t)$ does not converge at all as $t\to+\infty$.

Comment: I think that's correct. But there must be another way to prove this without having all this work. Please check my question about autonomous differential equations and please try to found another simple solution (this one isn't complicated at all)

Comment: @Raphaël: See my edit.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thanks for your help.